# Copy all files whose hashes don't match

Tags: command-line, cp, hash

I currently have a hash list (known good) of a selection of various files. I want to copy all files when their hashes do not appear in the hash list to a separate directory.

I have got the `md5deep` section of the command working (detecting all files which don't appear on the list). I am working on the copy section of the command.

Looking at the cp man pages the -t option `" copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY"` thus the `~/Desktop/Unknowjpg/` is the Destination directory and `~/Desktop/physical/output/jpg/` is the source.

Running the below command I get the error message `` "cp: omitting directory `/home/daniel/Desktop/physical/output/jpg/'" ``

```
 md5deep -x Hashes.txt jpg/*.jpg | cp -t ~/Desktop/Unknownjpg/ ~/Desktop/physical/output/jpg/
```

Comment: You'll need to add a -r (recursive) flag to the cp command to allow it to copy directories.

Comment: Copies everything over. May need to change the piping or cp flags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using xargs, e.g.

```
md5deep -x Hashes.txt jpg/*.jpg | xargs cp -t ~/Desktop/physical/output/jpg/
```

You don't need to give a SOURCE argument to the `cp` command because the pipe from md5deep is the 'source' of the files to copy.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted